# What is the difference between string in the code vs string from file

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I would like to `Instantiate` an object in the code. At that time, if I use `string` in the code, the function works fine. However, if I take the string from a file, it does not work.

Then I try to compare both `string` and it seems something different.

This is the loading function.

```cs
private string assemblyObjPath;

void Start()
{
    LoadConfigFile();
    if (assemblyObjPath == "scene1")
    {
        Debug.Log("True");
    }
    else
    {        
        Debug.Log("False"); // False
    }

    assemblyObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load(assemblyObjPath)) as GameObject;
    // ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
}

private void LoadConfigFile()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cfgFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
    string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    string[] arr = str.Split(char.Parse("\n"));
    string[] arr0 = arr[0].Split(char.Parse(" "));

    assemblyObjPath = arr0[1];

    Debug.Log("assemblyObjPath : " + assemblyObjPath); // assemblyObjPath : scene1
}
```

This is the input file.

```
assemblyObjPath scene1
```

What is the difference between the two of them?
Thank you.

Comment: Note: you can use `' '` instead of `char.Parse(" ")`.

Comment: Check the length of the string you're reading from the file after splitting it, you may have trailing spaces or carriage returns etc

Comment: @ThomasWeller Start is called by Unity. The LoadConfigFile is called at the beginning of Start.

Comment: @Diado You are right. The length of `string` from code is 7 and that of from file is 6. Something is in the string. maybe '\n'

Comment: Since you split at `\n`, I guess the `\r` is still inside. CRLF is `\r\n` on Windows

Comment: In order to split in both cases you could try using `string[] arr = str.Split(new char[] {'\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` and additionally use e.g. `if(string.Equals(assemblyObjPath.Trim() , "scene1"))` to eliminate any whitespace

Comment: The function works now by using `assemblyObjPath = assemblyObjPath.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");`. Thanks